# Is it possible to create *Dependencies node in package.json for npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json

I am using node packages and I use npm to install this dependencies. I have different types of dependencies:

- production, deps of this type  are described in `dependencies` section
- development, deps of this type are described in `devDependencies` section

Actually, I have one more type of dependencies: test dependencies (actually, e2e tests and unit tests deps :) ).

Is it possible to create some node in pacakge json and bind npm installer to this node? So I will use `npm install --only={test}` and only dependencies from `testDependencies` will be installed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that.

One **workaround** would be to have two package.json files. For example *prod_package.json* and *dev_package.json*

Then you can specify which one to use accordingly.

Comment: Sad. That will cause two names, two versions etc in both *package.json files. Package.json must be valid :(

Answer (score 0):

npm install `enter dependencies` --save-dev